# statusText always shows OK for StatusCode 401 where as expecting "Unauthorized" for 401

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I dont understand why do I always see statusText as OK for StatusCode 401, whereas expecting "Unauthorized" for 401. Below is my code snippit. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
public class BuggyController : BaseApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("auth")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetSecret()
    {
        return "secret text";
    }
}

//Anguler call to webApi
get401Error(){
this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'buggy/auth')
.subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

}

[Chrome response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEwDP.png)

Comment: Why do you need to use `statusText` for? Simply base all your logic on `statusCode`.

Answer (score 1):

After some code review in detail, I found that you're also using UseHttpsRedirection middleware. Your Angular app is running in development mode and there is no SSL. Both the API and Client are running without any certificate. So please remove UseHttpsRedirection middleware, then correct HttpErrorResponse is received. IT is in Startup.cs Configure method.

Comment this out: app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Also, could you share your Startup class for more details. It could also happen if CORS is configured in the wrong way.

Comment: Below is my Config method from Startup.cs
`public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddlewear>();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }`

Comment: Can you please comment out this and try : 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Also, you can make http instead of https on app.UseCors()

Answer (score 0):

Cool, I had the same issue, but I figured it out:

1. Comment this out: app.UseHttpsRedirection();
2. Instead of making any request with https://localhost:5001/api, please change it to http://localhost:5000/api/

That was my solution.

Comment: How is this different from the highest voted answer?

Comment: I added the way I did it, from API and UI.